# laravel count relation return Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on int

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get relation:

```
Package::whereIn('id', $cart_items)->with('course')->select('id', 'name')->get();
```

It return successfully as object, but now I need to count this relation, I did:

```
function courses(){
 return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Course', 'package_id','id');
}
    
public function getCourseCount()
{
 return $this->courses()->count();
}
```

And then:

```
Package::whereIn('id', $cart_items)->with('getCourseCount')->select('id', 'name')->get();
```

But give me this error:

> Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on int

Any idea?

--
*I also used `withCount` but it return empty array.*

```
Package::whereIn('id', $cart_items)->withCount('courses')->select('id', 'name')->get();
```

Comment: How did you query the `withCount` ?

Comment: You should call `withCount` after the `select`

Comment: Great. I also posted it as an answer. Don't forget to mark it as the correct answer, if it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#relationship-counting-and-custom-select-statements):

> If you're combining withCount with a select statement, ensure that you call withCount after the select method

So try the following code:

```php
Package::whereIn('id', $cart_items)->select('id', 'name')->withCount('courses')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

`withCount()` accepts a relation name as a parameter, so try this

```
Package::whereIn('id', $cart_items)->withCount('courses')->get();
```

without the `select()`

Comment: Okay but I don't want all columns of `Package` I used `select` for it, just `id` and `name`